# What is the best way to pass AWS credentials to a Docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I am running docker-container on Amazon EC2. Currently I have added AWS Credentials to Dockerfile. Could you please let me know the best way to do this?

Comment: How about if I am running a Docker container on my laptop which is supposed to also magically work in ECS when I push it there? I am gonna guess I use the --volume flag...someone must have already answered...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61367284/ecs-fargate-task-container-missing-aws-container-credentials-relative-uri?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 186, accepted):

The best way is to use IAM Role and do not deal with credentials at all. (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html )

Credentials could be retrieved from `http://169.254.169.254.....`  Since this is a private ip address, it could be accessible only from EC2 instances.

All modern AWS client libraries "know" how to fetch, refresh and use credentials from there. So in most cases you don't even need to know about it.  Just run ec2 with correct IAM role and you good to go.

As an option you can pass them at the runtime as environment variables ( i.e `docker run -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xyz -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=aaa myimage`)

You can access these environment variables by running printenv at the terminal.

Comment: Is there a good way to do this during local development/testing that doesn't compromise security in production? I'd love to make sure an image works without deploying it fully.

Comment: an alternative that I posted with environment variables works fine in dev/local environment.

Comment: I wonder if this is a typo, but I need to enter `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, not `AWS_SECRET_KEY`, anyway your answer was very helpful. Thank You.

Comment: @honktronic - I asked myself the same question and came up with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49956609/13087

Comment: To put it simply (for those who get to this answer the same way I did); A docker container running on EC2 will inherit the same role as the host instance. (I needed an "ELI5" like this when AWS CLI commands in my containers mysteriously worked despite there being no credentials passed to them!)

Comment: Easy way to get the key values from your local profile to assign to environment variable for development purposes (as suggested in https://cameroneckelberry.co/words/getting-aws-credentials-into-a-docker-container-without-hardcoding-it):    "aws --profile default configure get aws_access_key_id"

Comment: Will this work for windows docker containers or just linux containers?  We are dealing with windows docker containers running in windows EC2 and ECS with  EC2 windows launch type . Using AWS SDK can i access an AWS service(ex secret manager) by assumed role of host EC2 instance ?

Comment: This is so simple and saved me so much time.. thanks @Vor

Comment: while passing in the key and secret via env vars is definitely the easiest, it's discouraged, as you'll now have a dependency on long term credentials. IMO, this whole discussion shines a bright light on the horrible disconnect presented (and not at all addressed in the AWS SDK docs) between using the sdk locally, during development, and in production on one of their instances in whatever service you may be using. It's unfortunate, to say the least. I mean, just reading the work arounds demonstrates how crappy this is. Local, local with docker, containerized deployment... all different... meh

Comment: So @wkhatch, how would you solve the problem?

Comment: Since I was doing local testing I used @BMitch's answer above. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56077990/175759
Specifically the part where you use `docker run -v $HOME/.aws/credentials:/home/app/.aws/credentials:ro your_image` or the alternative for a docker-compose file.

Comment: How do we setup aws creds when our k8s cluster is out of aws or in on-premise cluster?

Answer (score 253):

A lot has changed in Docker since this question was asked, so here's an attempt at an updated answer.

First, specifically with AWS credentials on containers already running inside of the cloud, using IAM roles as [Vor suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36357388/596285) is a really good option. If you can do that, then add one more plus one to his answer and skip the rest of this.

---

Once you start running things outside of the cloud, or have a different type of secret, there are two key places that I **recommend against** storing secrets:

1. Environment variables: when these are defined on a container, every process inside the container has access to them, they are visible via /proc, apps may dump their environment to stdout where it gets stored in the logs, and most importantly, they appear in clear text when you inspect the container.
2. In the image itself: images often get pushed to registries where many users have pull access, sometimes without any credentials required to pull the image. Even if you delete the secret from one layer, the image can be disassembled with common Linux utilities like `tar` and the secret can be found from the step where it was first added to the image.

---

So what other options are there for secrets in Docker containers?

**Option A:** If you need this secret only during the build of your image, cannot use the secret before the build starts, and do not have access to BuildKit yet, then a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) is a best of the bad options. You would add the secret to the initial stages of the build, use it there, and then copy the output of that stage without the secret to your release stage, and only push that release stage to the registry servers. This secret is still in the image cache on the build server, so I tend to use this only as a last resort.

**Option B:** Also during build time, if you can use BuildKit which was released in 18.09, there are currently [experimental features](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md) to allow the injection of secrets as a volume mount for a single RUN line. That mount does not get written to the image layers, so you can access the secret during build without worrying it will be pushed to a public registry server. The resulting Dockerfile looks like:

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM python:3
RUN pip install awscli
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=aws,target=/root/.aws/credentials aws s3 cp s3://... ...
```

And you build it with a command in 18.09 or newer like:

```bash
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t your_image --secret id=aws,src=$HOME/.aws/credentials .
```

**Option C:** At runtime on a single node, without Swarm Mode or other orchestration, you can mount the credentials as a read only volume. Access to this credential requires the same access that you would have outside of docker to the same credentials file, so it's no better or worse than the scenario without docker. Most importantly, the contents of this file should not be visible when you inspect the container, view the logs, or push the image to a registry server, since the volume is outside of that in every scenario. This does require that you copy your credentials on the docker host, separate from the deploy of the container. (Note, anyone with the ability to run containers on that host can view your credential since access to the docker API is root on the host and root can view the files of any user. If you don't trust users with root on the host, then don't give them docker API access.)

For a `docker run`, this looks like:

```bash
docker run -v $HOME/.aws/credentials:/home/app/.aws/credentials:ro your_image
```

Or for a compose file, you'd have:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: your_image
    volumes:
    - $HOME/.aws/credentials:/home/app/.aws/credentials:ro
```

**Option D:** With orchestration tools like Swarm Mode and Kubernetes, we now have secrets support that's better than a volume. With Swarm Mode, the file is encrypted on the manager filesystem (though the decryption key is often there too, allowing the manager to be restarted without an admin entering a decrypt key). More importantly, the secret is only sent to the workers that need the secret (running a container with that secret), it is only stored in memory on the worker, never disk, and it is injected as a file into the container with a tmpfs mount. Users on the host outside of swarm cannot mount that secret directly into their own container, however, with open access to the docker API, they could extract the secret from a running container on the node, so again, limit who has this access to the API. From compose, this secret injection looks like:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

secrets:
  aws_creds:
    external: true

services:
  app:
    image: your_image
    secrets:
    - source: aws_creds
      target: /home/user/.aws/credentials
      uid: '1000'
      gid: '1000'
      mode: 0700
```

You turn on swarm mode with `docker swarm init` for a single node, then follow the directions for adding additional nodes. You can create the secret externally with `docker secret create aws_creds $HOME/.aws/credentials`. And you deploy the compose file with `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml stack_name`.

I often version my secrets using a script from: https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-config-update

**Option E:** Other tools exist to manage secrets, and my favorite is [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) because it gives the ability to create time limited secrets that automatically expire. Every application then gets its own set of tokens to request secrets, and those tokens give them the ability to request those time limited secrets for as long as they can reach the vault server. That reduces the risk if a secret is ever taken out of your network since it will either not work or be quick to expire. The functionality specific to AWS for Vault is documented at https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/aws/index.html

Comment: what to do when I don't use docker compose?

Comment: @Jun711 the docker run on the previous line didn't cover that?

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. This is the command I used `docker run -v $HOME/.aws/credentials:/home/app/.aws/credentials:ro -it -p 8080:8080 imageName:tagName`. The boto3 error message was `Unable to locate credentials`. I am not sure if it matters but the permission for credentials file is `ls -la $HOME/.aws/credentials` -rw-------

Comment: @Jun711 if you're on linux, the uid of the file on the host needs to match the uid of the container user. Otherwise, I'd recommend posting a new question with a [mcve] to get help with your question.

Comment: I am on Mac, I changed the container path to root instead of `/home/app/` and it worked. `docker run -v $HOME/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials:ro -it -p 8080:8080 imageName:tagName` Do you know how I can access that root dir? I used `docker exec imageId ls -la` but I couldn't find my aws credentials file there

Comment: Yes, worked for me: `docker run -d -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=development -v "%UserProfile%\.aws\credentials":/root/.aws/credentials:ro --name containerName imageName`

Comment: What about Docker Compose secrets?

Comment: @its.me.adam I haven't dug into the implementation, but I believe that's syntactic sugar on option c.

Comment: @BMitch I think so too. Which of these options do you recommend? It seems as if E (Vault) is your favourite. Some say Swarm is fine as Vault is more for complex apps/scale. Would you still go with Vault for very simple apps? The expiration feature seems nice and I feel that your versioning in option D is verging into more complex territory where it may just make sense to go straight for Vault. I guess my condensed question is, do you ever prefer to use D with your versioning, instead of Vault?

Comment: @its.me.adam each option has tradeoffs and different scenarios will have different preferred options.

Answer (score 70):

Yet another approach is to create temporary read-only volume in docker-compose.yaml. AWS CLI and SDK (like boto3 or AWS SDK for Java etc.) are looking for `default` profile in `~/.aws/credentials` file.

If you want to use other profiles, you just need also to export AWS_PROFILE variable before running `docker-compose` command.

`export AWS_PROFILE=some_other_profile_name`

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  service-name:
    image: docker-image-name:latest
    environment:
      - AWS_PROFILE=${AWS_PROFILE}
    volumes:
      - ~/.aws/:/root/.aws:ro
```

In this example, I used root user on docker. If you are using other user, just change `/root/.aws` to user home directory.

`:ro` - stands for read-only docker volume

It is very helpful when you have multiple profiles in `~/.aws/credentials` file and you are also using MFA. Also helpful when you want to locally test docker-container before deploying it on ECS on which you have IAM Roles, but locally you don't.

Comment: On windows .aws` catalogue is located `"%UserProfile%\.aws"`. So I assume that you have to change:  `- ~/.aws/:/root/.aws:ro` to `- %UserProfile%\.aws:/root/.aws:ro`

Comment: This will only work with single build processes and not multistage.

Comment: @wlarcheveque Care to elaborate?

Comment: Be VERY careful using the `- host:container` syntax, if the file/folder doesn't exist on the host it gets created (as root) and the awscli won't thank you for feeding it a zero byte file.  You should use the "long form" that specifies the type is bind, the host path, and the container path on separate lines, this fails if the file doesn't exist, which is what you want in your docker-compose.dev.yml but not in your docker-compose.yml (prod/AWS deploy).

Comment: Note that with `php:7.4-fpm` docker container, the HOME_DIR as defined in AWS is `/var/www`. So my volume configuration is `~/.aws:/var/www/.aws:ro`.

Answer (score 41):

Another approach is to pass the keys from the host machine to the docker container. You may add the following lines to the `docker-compose` file.

```yaml
services:
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
```

Comment: The correct region environment variable is AWS_REGION. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151982/aws-java-sdk-unable-to-find-a-region-via-the-region-provider-chain

Comment: Please check the official doc which mentions `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

Comment: When I used AWS_DEFAULT_REGION, I got an exception that a default region could not be found. My search led to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html which specifies AWS_REGION environment variable, and that worked for me.

Comment: If you are using temporary credentials then you may also need `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}`

Comment: do you need to export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID etc. using `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="myaccesskeyid"? the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID env var was undefined for me.

Comment: Note that different SDKs use different environment variables to determine region. The python (boto3) and JavaScript SDKs look for `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`, while the Java SDK looks for `AWS_REGION`, which probably accounts for the differences @JohnCamerin and @prafi encountered. Yes, this is certifiably insane.

Comment: note: cis recommendations and best practices in general ... would suggest ... DO NOT put secrets in your environment. Use files and read from them, where/when you need those. Setting global env vars like this, all your processes within that container do have access to those data, always, ... and they could leak, as part of a crash/trace/debug-data...

Answer (score 6):

The following one-liner works for me even when my credentials are set up by [aws-okta](https://github.com/segmentio/aws-okta) or [saml2aws](https://github.com/Versent/saml2aws):

```
$ docker run -v$HOME/.aws:/root/.aws:ro \
            -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID \
            -e AWS_CA_BUNDLE \
            -e AWS_CLI_FILE_ENCODING \
            -e AWS_CONFIG_FILE \
            -e AWS_DEFAULT_OUTPUT \
            -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION \
            -e AWS_PAGER \
            -e AWS_PROFILE \
            -e AWS_ROLE_SESSION_NAME \
            -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY \
            -e AWS_SESSION_TOKEN \
            -e AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE \
            -e AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS \
            amazon/aws-cli s3 ls
```

Please note that for advanced use cases you might need to allow `rw` (read-write) permissions, so omit the `ro` (read-only) limitation when mounting the `.aws` volume in `-v$HOME/.aws:/root/.aws:ro`

Comment: I was using something like `-e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}`, but I just realized from you answer here that if they are named the same I can leave it out. Thx.

Comment: I did something similar to above with the `-e AWS` stuff and got it working, but I didn't include the `-v $HOME/.aws:/root/.aws:ro` because I couldn't get it working by itself as another solution here suggested. Why do you include both the `-v` line and the `-e` lines here?

Answer (score 4):

Volume mounting is noted in this thread but as of `docker-compose v3.2 +` you can Bind Mount.

For example, if you have a file named `.aws_creds` in the root of your project:

In your service for the compose file do this for volumes:

```
volumes:
     # normal volume mount, already shown in thread
  - ./.aws_creds:/root/.aws/credentials
    # way 2, note this requires docker-compose v 3.2+
  - type: bind                         
    source: .aws_creds              # from local
    target: /root/.aws/credentials  # to the container location
```

Using this idea, you can publicly store your docker images on docker-hub because your `aws credentials` will not physically be in the image...to have them associated, you must have the correct directory structure locally where the container is started (i.e. pulling from Git)

Answer (score 4):

This will work for local development, and uses your `~/.aws` directory and/or can be overridden with environment variables or temporary access tokens.
Temporary access tokens are the preferred method for local development: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  my-container-name:
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      - AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
      - AWS_PROFILE
      - AWS_REGION
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
    secrets:
      - source: aws
        target: /home/appuser/.aws
        uid: "1000"
        gid: "1000"
        mode: 0700

secrets:
  aws:
    file: "~/.aws"
```

The above assumes you are not running your processes as `root` (please don't!), and are instead running them as `appuser`.  If you really want to run them as root, replace `/home/appuser/` with `/root/`

I recommend adding this to your `Dockerfile`, usually right before the entrypoint/cmd lines:

```
RUN groupadd -r -g 1000 appuser && useradd -m -r -u 1000 -g appuser appuser
USER appuser
```

For actual production deployments, assuming K8s, you should make use of IAM Roles and Kubernetes service accounts: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/
Better explainer: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/diving-into-iam-roles-for-service-accounts/

Comment: This is a great solution, but it broke my CI process, which I fixed with a `touch ~/.aws` before starting my docker containers.

Answer (score 2):

You could create `~/aws_env_creds` containing:

```bash
touch ~/aws_env_creds
chmod 777 ~/aws_env_creds
vi ~/aws_env_creds
```

Add these value (replace the key of yours):

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AK_FAKE_KEY_88RD3PNY
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=BividQsWW_FAKE_KEY_MuB5VAAsQNJtSxQQyDY2C
```

Press "esc" to save the file.

Run and test the container:

```yaml
 my_service:
      build: .
      image: my_image
      env_file:
        - ~/aws_env_creds
```

Comment: It's a working solution, I would avoid to set the file with `777` permissions, as any other user with access to the host will be able to read the credentials file... Not very good, as the point of using env variables is to keep crendentials away from anyone/anything that is not the aws service that needs them! Maybe [744 is more appropriate](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-744/)

Answer (score 1):

If someone still face the same issue after following the instructions mentioned in accepted answer then make sure that you are not passing environment variables from two different sources. In my case I was passing environment variables to `docker run` via a file and as parameters which was causing the variables passed as parameters show no effect.

So the following command did not work for me:

```
docker run --env-file ./env.list -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ABCD -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=PQRST IMAGE_NAME:v1.0.1
```

Moving the aws credentials into the mentioned `env.list` file helped.

Comment: Hi Abhay - you are missing an "S" on AWS_SECRET_ACCES_KEY

Comment: Thanks @lukass77 for pointing that out. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

for php apache docker the following command works

```
docker run --rm -d -p 80:80 --name my-apache-php-app -v "$PWD":/var/www/html -v ~/.aws:/.aws --env AWS_PROFILE=mfa php:7.2-apache
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on some of previous answers, I built my own as follows.
My project structure:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── code
│   └── main.py
├── credentials
├── docker-compose.yml
└── requirements.txt
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./credentials:/root/.aws/credentials
      - ./code:/home/app
```

My `Docker` file:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install --upgrade awscli

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /home/app

CMD python main.py
```