# Adding credentials to AmazonKinesisAsyncClientBuilder

Tags: amazon-kinesis, alpakka

Elsewhere in StackOverflow ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151982/aws-java-sdk-unable-to-find-a-region-via-the-region-provider-chain)), access to AWS S3 is done like this:

```
AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3Client.builder()
    .withRegion("us-east-1")
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
    .build();
```

I'd like to use this pattern for `AmazonKinesisAsyncClientBuilder`, but there aren't any methods to set the region, or credentials.

i.e. this cannot compile:

```
  AmazonKinesisAsyncClientBuilder
    .withRegion("eu-west-1")
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
    .build();
```

I'm bringing in creds from a custom file (a normal thing in AWS); does `AmazonKinesisAsyncClientBuilder` only work with the defaults?

Using AWS SDK for Java 2.5.1

Planning to read Kinesis via [AlpakkaKinesis](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/kinesis.html), but that may not be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Need to do it with

```
AmazonKinesisAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
  .withRegion("eu-west-1")
  .withCredentials(...)
  .build()
```

Unlike S3, there does not seem to be `AmazonKinesisAsync.builder()` so the cases vary slightly.