# What is the difference between AWS_DEFAULT_REGION and AWS_REGION system variables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Some examples in internet have `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` env variable set but some others `AWS_REGION`. What is the difference? Which services use one or another?

Comment: Both are same, they have updated env variable to `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`, here is the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` and `AWS_REGION` is the same.

They first introduce `AWS_REGION` in SDK and then `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` comes later.
it is also asked in their [aws-cli](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/735)

> **AWS_DEFAULT_REGION**  - Specifies the AWS Region to send the request to.
>   If defined, this environment variable overrides the value for the
>   profile setting region. You can override this environment variable by
>   using the --region command line parameter.
>   [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html)

Comment: Sure, conceptually they are the same (just region names). But, depending on the SDK, you might use one over the other.

Answer (score 30):

They are ***not*** the same: one works in some situations and the other works in other situations.

e.g. I just learned that `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` does not work with the AWS Java API library. See [Force AWS library to obtain region from environment inside docker cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60532462/)

cf. [44151982](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151982), [36354423](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354423), [Github aws/aws-sdk-go#2103](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/2103)

Comment: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION works in python boto3 and the cdk. AWS_REGION doesn't work for boto, cdk. 

The name kind of make you think they would complement each other but that's isn't true. For python it's this and java it's that while people work in multiple languages at a time. Such a mess.

Answer (score 18):

`AWS_REGION` is the new/preferred. All SDKs use `AWS_REGION` except boto3 and AWS CLIv1 [Compatibility between SDKs page in Amazon official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/feature-region.html#feature-region-sdk-compat).

Unfortunately, boto3 will not add `AWS_REGION` until the next major release which is not even planned as of 2023-12-14 (see [this comment](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3620#issuecomment-1462661383))

> boto3 and the AWS CLI v1 are exceptions in that they use AWS_DEFAULT_REGION. It was called out in the v2 migration changes page that AWS_REGION was added for v2. It is an unfortunate inconsistency between the SDKs but as you suggested, it would be a breaking change to adjust the credential precedence at this point, and so I don't think this could be considered **until the next major version of the SDK**.

The AWS CLI v2 supports both `AWS_REGION` and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` and in the context of the CLI they are the same (`AWS_REGION` takes precedence if set). See [Environment variables to configure the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html). AWS CLI v1 used `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` only and in AWS CLI v2 they introduced `AWS_REGION` see [aws cli v2 migration notes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cliv2-migration-changes.html).

So in general we could say that you better set **both** `AWS_REGION` and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` to the same value if you want to be sure (like if you don't know what SDK was used to build the application). Otherwise you need to use

- AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

  - AWS CLIv1
  - Python SDK boto3 1.xxx
- AWS_REGION

  - AWS CLIv2
  - Go SDK
  - Javascript SDK
  - Java SDK
  - all other SDKs in general

Answer (score 3):

I have learned, the hard way, that they're not the same. Depending on what SDK you use (or cli) read the config documentation for that specific SDK. Certain SDKs (e.g. Golang) uses `AWS_REGION`, while others obey `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`. This is not a precedence issue, in Go, it doesn't even care about `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`.

Answer (score 2):

The AWS_DEFAULT_REGION environment variable belongs to awscli.  AWS_REGION is recognized/respected by a number of other projects/platforms.

Namespacing environment variables is hard/important.

Answer (score 0):

**AWS_REGION**

The AWS SDK compatible environment variable that specifies the AWS Region to send the request to.

**If defined**, this environment variable **overrides** the values in the environment variable **AWS_DEFAULT_REGION** and the profile setting region. You can override this environment variable by using the --region command line parameter.

source : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html