# Unable to access aws environment variable within the rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I am unable to access **ENV['AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI']** variable inside the rails application. The application is running on the AWS Fargate container. When I am inside the container I can see the environment variable. I can also access the environment **AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI** variable from the rails console. But unable to access within the application. I have tried almost everything but no luck for me.

What I have tried so far

Added the variable in the Docker file

```
ENV AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI=${AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI}
```

Tried to modify the docker user. Also, try to run the application from the root user

**Note**: The environment variable is dynamically created by AWS

Comment: If the environment variable is available inside the container. Can you double-check the spelling of the Environment variable name inside the application??

Comment: The spelling is correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61367284/ecs-fargate-task-container-missing-aws-container-credentials-relative-uri