# Pass AWS credentials into docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-cli, credentials

I want to create a docker image with my testing aws credentials. This is my current Dockerfile looks like. What I want to do is copy my `.aws` folder into container and use that data, without passing them through command line. is it possible? then how can I do that? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: since you have ‘COPY . .’ the files should already be there (at /usr/src/app)

Comment: @MilanMarkovic I checked it, but only file I can see is Dockerfile

Comment: you would have to copy the credentials file next to the Docker file yourself,  the build can reach only files inside the build folder. but don't do that, hardcoding credentials is considered as bad and usafe practice for many reasons

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to pass AWS credentials to a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354423/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-aws-credentials-to-a-docker-container)

Answer (score 6):

I believe its better to let container orchestration services do this in production, but if you want to test your code/app or just want to do it that way, you could do the following:

in the docker-compose.yml file mount the aws credentials folder as a volume:

```
    volumes:
    - /home/user/.aws:/root/.aws
```

if using docker only, mount it using the -v flag:

```
docker run -v /home/user/.aws:/root/.aws
```

Answer (score 3):

> What I want to do is copy my .aws folder into container

I would advice not to copy the credential directly to the docker image. If you need to use the aws api, there are better ways to pass the credentials at the run time (regardless using the docker directly, compose or under kubernetes).

1. You can pass the aws credentials as  environment variables  `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. If using kubernetes, there is great concept of *secrets*
2. mount the file `.aws/credentials` as a mounted volume

Edit (I forgot this one) :

3. if the pods are running on AWS EKS, you can assign [the pod an IAM execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/pod-execution-role.html). That was you don't need to pass any credentials.

Comment: can you show how number 2 is done , like an example of docker-compse.yml file please