# Image base to connect AWS services

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, amazon-s3

I want to set up the aws credential to connect the AWS Services. The problem is, I have an application, this appication try to access to the S3 bucket. So if we want to connect to the services, we need to setup the aws configure right?

Because the s3 bucket I'm using need the token to access and it will expired every 1 hour. So I'm using the AWS Access Key and Secret Access Key to generate the token. However, its not the problem because I already had an submit job to spin up the container

What I want to do is **create an image base** having the aws credential, after that the  application which want to connect to the aws services can use that image base and it will available access to aws services

But I don't have any idea how I can make it possible. Can you help me to give me some advice

Comment: *"So if we want to connect to the services, we need to setup the aws configure right?"* - no, the credentials can also be available as environment variables or retrieved from a metadata / credential service. Rarely / never do applications actually rely on `aws configure`.

Answer (score 1):

`What I want to do is create an image base having the aws credential...`

You could leak your AWS credential if you saved it in the image. This is definitely a **no go**. There are many ways to pass credential on-the-fly, here's a good [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354423/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-aws-credentials-to-a-docker-container) discussing the subject, including the simplest use case like using environment variables.