# How to initial my container in order to assumeRole?

Tags: docker, boto3, aws-cli, aws-sts

My dockerFile looks like

```
FROM python:3.9
RUN mkdir /app
COPY aws_spot_connect_test.py /app/aws_spot_connect.py
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["sleep","1800"]
```

I want make actions on my aws account but withRole I don't want enter ACCESS/_KEY and SECRET to my container since it's not secure.

I run the docker with `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash adi20022023:v2`

I wanted make manually the actions I should do in the script.

I created a role which is a trust-relationship to itself.
I set it as as env param.
`export ROLE_ARN=xxxxx`

But when I tried `aws sts get-caller-identity` or I try assume the role I can't because of
`Unable to locate credentials`

What can I do in order make aws actions without enter my ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ?

Comment: Running locally? Provide access keys. Running on e.g. AWS EC2? Credentials should already be set if you configured a profile when creating the instance.

Comment: For now I am running it locally, but I want it will be on ECR later. I don't want insert my access_key and secret_access_key into the container, from what I know it is not reccommended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to pass AWS credentials to a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354423/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-aws-credentials-to-a-docker-container)

Comment: All of those ways combined volumes or accessKey and secretAccessKey I was thinking that I can use just role, and let it assumeRole to itself and then assumeRole to other role with tempoary credentials I got from the firstRole.

Comment: No, you cannot just use a role, a role is not something you can authenticate with. You can write a wrapper that takes the role and your credentials, assume the role and passes the resulting credentials to the container / env.